# Win32 API: How to track changes in editor control

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I am beginner is WinAPI. I have an editor control (window with class "Edit"). I need to track all changes in it. That is I need know what and where was added or removed. For example, in WPF I can get this information through event TextChanged of TextBox. Is it possible via standard functions of Windows API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows will send your parent window an [`EN_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676(v=vs.85).aspx) notification message when text in the edit control changes. It's up to you to work out **what** changed - the system doesn't do that for you automatically.